# Densify tool equivalent for Basic ArcGIS License?

Tags: arcmap, geoprocessing, tools

I'm looking for a tool/script/quicker process that does the same thing as the standard license's densify tool. I'm only using a basic license though. Just wondering if there was anything out there that did something similar.

Comment: It is possible to do quite a bit using the `arcpy.Geometry` object. What particular method of densifying are you looking for - do you need to convert arcs to polylines or something else? And using what algorithm?

Comment: I wanted to create a smooth line using the Smooth tool(Bezier curves) in the advanced editing toolbar, and then add vertices every 3 metres.

Comment: Advanced Editing - Generalize (with a small offset).  This will blow away curves.

Comment: I'd like to keep as much of the curve as I can. But i want a vertice every 3 metres or so.

Comment: Cloning a line with additional vertices is as simple as calculating the distance and slope of each segment, then determining how to allocate the parts which are not evenly divisible. Since coding questions here should contain code, please put in a good-faith effort.